# Replace string in column by string in next column (one file)

Tags: perl, bash, parsing, awk

I would like to replace the "." that is in the middle of the column two, by the string in column 3.

Input file (tab-delimited):

```
0   AAAAAAAAGTTT.TATAGTAATATA   T   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
1   AAAAAAACGACG.ATTTTACAATAC   C   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
2   AAAAAAAGCAGG.CATTATCGCTGG   G   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
3   AAAAAAAGGAAC.GTGGAACGTTGG   A   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
5   AAAAAACACAAC.ATTGAGCAACTT   A   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
6   AAAAAACACCCA.CTGTGAAAGAAA   T   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
9   AAAAAACGCCAA.GTCAGCTACAAA   C   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
```

Desired output:

```
0   AAAAAAAAGTTTTTATAGTAATATA   T   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
1   AAAAAAACGACGCATTTTACAATAC   C   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
2   AAAAAAAGCAGGGCATTATCGCTGG   G   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
3   AAAAAAAGGAACAGTGGAACGTTGG   A   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
5   AAAAAACACAACAATTGAGCAACTT   A   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
6   AAAAAACACCCATCTGTGAAAGAAA   T   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
9   AAAAAACGCCAACGTCAGCTACAAA   C   x   HPNK_05032012_new.fna
```

Comment: Hi mpapec, your one-liner is just deleting ".", 0       AAAAAAAAGTTTTATAGTAATATA        T       x       HPNK_05032012_new.fna

Comment: How does it differ from desired output?

Comment: @mpapec: in the desired output he REPLACES . with the content of the next column

Comment: @OlivierDulac tnx for comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$ awk '{sub("\.", $3, $2)}1' file
0 AAAAAAAAGTTTTTATAGTAATATA T x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
1 AAAAAAACGACGCATTTTACAATAC C x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
2 AAAAAAAGCAGGGCATTATCGCTGG G x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
3 AAAAAAAGGAACAGTGGAACGTTGG A x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
5 AAAAAACACAACAATTGAGCAACTT A x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
6 AAAAAACACCCATCTGTGAAAGAAA T x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
9 AAAAAACGCCAACGTCAGCTACAAA C x HPNK_05032012_new.fna
```

It is basically replacing the `.` with the 3rd field by using the `sub()` function. Then `1` performs the awk's default behaviour: `{print $0}`.

Since your question shows spaces in between columns, my output is just showing one space. In case your input uses tabs, add tab as field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub("\.", $3, $2)}1' file
```

Comment: at the second column ,`.` are not removed for me

Comment: @MortezaLSC but does your sample code contain tabs in between columns? Note that if not, the second field won't be the second column.

Comment: Hmmm...I copied what popnard wrote...Yes..worked great...thank you

Comment: My input file is tab-separated and is not working the second fedorqui's command, why?

Comment: To make sure it is tab-separated, @popnard , try doing `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $2} file` to make sure `awk` is taking the second column as the second field.

Comment: first line from your check: AAAAAAAAGTTT.TATAGTAATATA. I'm on a MAC, maybe try in linux?

Comment: It is difficult to say, @popnard . Maybe you can just use the first command and then replace spaces with tab: `awk ... | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '\t'`

Comment: I have the same output when doing the same check you suggested but specifying space as FS.

Comment: Not working under Ubuntu linux 12.04, neither first or second command

Comment: sed 's/\./HELLO/' and awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub("HELLO", $3, $2)}1' worked

Comment: Define not working, @popnard . It is pretty fine for me on Ubuntu 13, using `mawk`. In my case I had to escape the dot, maybe without escaping it...

Comment: @popnard could you give it a try with `sub(/\./, $3, $2)`? That's what anubhava suggested in his [deleted] answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$F[1] =~ s/[.]/$F[2]/; print "@F"' file
```

or shorter,

```
perl -ape 's/[.]/$F[2]/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk, which will keep the original format

```
awk '$19=$33' FS="" OFS="" file
```